# AttributeError: type object 'ClassName' has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, attributeerror

This is my models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class SelectScent(models.Model):
   client = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', 
   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   scent = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   text = models.TextField()
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
   select_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

   def publish(self):
       self.select_date = timezone.now()
       self.save()

   def __str__(self):
       return self.scent
```

when I type SelectScent.objects.all() i get the above error. 
python version : 3.6.1

Comment: ok, I can see your error from the title. But you 'd better put it to content box.

Comment: You want `.objects`, not `.object`.